# ASP.NET Core MVC - Apply multiple Model Binders to object

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is it possible to pass an object through multiple Model Binders?

Currently I populate an object using the `[FromBody]` attribute. After the object has been created I'd also like to apply a second custom model binder that retrieves the latitude and longitude for a UK postcode and assigns it to the object (or marks the model as InValid if one doesn't exist).

When I assign my custom model binder to the class using the `ModelBinder` attribute the `BodyModelBinder` is no longer used. Without this I'll have to populate all the fields within my custom model binder.

I've tried inheriting the `BodyModelBinder` in my custom model binder but this throws an error.

Is it possible to apply multiple model binders or is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: No, but that's not the best way to handle this anyways. Model binders are for literally *binding data to models* - not validation. The validation happens at bind time because it makes sense then, and provides an easy way to incorporate actual binding errors such as trying to stuff a string in an int, etc. For your case here, you just need additional validation. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I've reworded the question to make it clear that validation isn't the only purpose. It's the encapsulation of retrieving the lat/long of a postcode and adding it to the object that I'm interested in.